# Pytorch - Do dataloader workers prepare samples or batches?

Tags: pytorch

When making a pytorch dataloader and specifying num_workers = k, what does each worker actually do? Lets say my batch size is 8. Does each worker gather 1 sample until we have 8, then concat them along the batch dimension? Or does each worker construct its own batch and keep them in RAM until they are ready to be sent to gpu?

Answer (score 0):

Workers prefetch batches and you can specify how many batches each worker should prefetch. Look at '''prefetch_factor''' for [data loader](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html). Therefore, if the prefetch factor is 2 and you have 2 workers they try to prefetch 4 batches.